# Is a session always created when using express js?

Tags: node.js, session, express

Assuming one sets the `cookieParser` in a Node application using Express JS, does it mean that a session will always be created if none is not available in the incoming request?

```
self.app.use(express.bodyParser());
self.app.use(express.cookieParser());
self.app.use(express.session({...]);
```

In other words, does `req.session` will ever be `null` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the session middleware will put a session object on each request given your code above. Not the cookie parser has one well-defined job: parse the `cookie` header from HTTP header key/value to JS object. End of story. It's the session middleware that handles creation and population of the session object.